# How to resolve Django migrate stuck?

Tags: python, django

After I tried to `makemigrations`/`migrate` a change (adding a default value to a `DateTimeField` for testing) on my `MySQL` database with `Django 2.0.2` it run into an error as I formatted the date wrong. Now after

- removing the default value
- changing the default value
- removing the table and recreating the model

`python manage.py migrate` still shows the following error (last line):

```
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ["'02.02.2012' value has an invalid format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format."]
```

Like I said: I allready changed my code to (excerpt):

```
class Task(models.Model):
    uploaddate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

and run `makemigrations` several times.

Why does `migrate` keep on showing my former mistake and wont import the new attribute correctly? Is this possibly a bug? Can I sort of "reset" `migrate`?

Comment: try deleting the last migration file and do manage.py makemigrations the_app

Comment: @DawitAbate Thanks for your quick help but it still runs into the same error.

Comment: Ah okay! My last migration file wasn't the one with the `02.02.` so this didn't work. It works now (as far as I can tell). Thanks for your help @DawitAbate and @Alasdair

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like one of your migration files contains the invalid date that you specified `'02.02.2012'` when running `manage.py makemigrations`.

You can editing the migration file and change `'02.02.2012'` to `datetime(2012,2,2)`. You may have to add the import `from datetime import datetime` to the migration file as well.

Comment: I already resolved the second part (as I stated in my question), could you rewrite the answer to fit how we actually resolved the problem (by deleting the file and then migrate)?

Comment: Every month I see people on Stack Overflow who have got into trouble because they deleted migrations or used `--fake` without thinking through the consequences, and now their database and migrations are out of sync. In your case, it was probably fine to delete the migration because the invalid date had prevented it from running, but in general this answer is safer than the suggestion in the comments to delete the migration. You’re welcome to write and accept your own answer if you don’t like this one.